# Get Payment details in QuoteManagement.php

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.2, sales-order, sales-quote

I have extended QuoteManagement.php file for split order. It's working fine, but I need payment details like credit card details to process the order. But I am not able to get payment details in file below are my code snap.

```
$quote111 = $checkoutSession->getQuote();  // or load by id
            $payment1 = $quote111->getPayment();
            $instance1 = $payment1->getMethodInstance();
            $ccNumber = $instance1->getInfoInstance()->getCcNumber();
            $ccMethod = $instance1->getInfoInstance()->getMethod();
            $ccType = $instance1->getInfoInstance()->getCcType();
            $ccExpYear = $instance1->getInfoInstance()->getCcExpYear();
            $ccExpMonth = $instance1->getInfoInstance()->getCcExpMonth();
```

I have also tried below code but no luck.

```
if ($paymentMethod) {
                $quoteSplit->getPayment()->setQuote($quoteSplit);
                $data = $paymentMethod->getData();
                $quoteSplit->getPayment()->importData($data);
            }
```

Below are my full code

```
$quoteRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface');
        $quoteFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
        $eventManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface');
        $checkoutSession = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        if (!($helper)) {
            return $result = $proceed($cartId, $paymentMethod);
        }
        $quote = $quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $paymentMethodString = $quote->getPayment()->getMethod();
        //  echo "<pre>"; print_r($quote->getData());

        /**/
        $checkoutMethod = $quote->getCheckoutMethod();
        $paymentMethod1 = $quote->getPayment()->getMethod();
        // $shippingAddress1 = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();
        //  $billingAddress1 = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getData();
        //   $customer = $this->checkCustomer($billingAddress1);
        $currency = $quote->getCurrency();


        /**/
        // get data from addresses and remove ids
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getData();
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();
        unset($billingAddress['id']);
        unset($billingAddress['quote_id']);
        unset($shippingAddress['id']);
        unset($shippingAddress['quote_id']);

        $temparray = [];
        foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $temparray[$item->getProduct()->getSku()][] = $item;
        }

        foreach ($temparray as $key => $items) {
            // init Quote Split
            $quoteSplit = $quoteFactory->create();
            $quoteSplit->setStoreId($quote->getStoreId());
            $quoteSplit->setCustomer($quote->getCustomer());
            $quoteSplit->setCustomerIsGuest($quote->getCustomerIsGuest());

            if ($quote->getCheckoutMethod() === self::METHOD_GUEST) {
                $quoteSplit->setCustomerId(null);
                $quoteSplit->setCustomerEmail($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail());
                $quoteSplit->setCustomerIsGuest(true);
                $quoteSplit->setCustomerGroupId(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
            }

            // save quoteSplit in order to have a quote id for item
            $quoteRepository->save($quoteSplit);

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                // add item
                $item->setId(null);
                $quoteSplit->addItem($item);
            }
            $tax = $item->getData('tax_amount');
            $rowTotal = $item->getData('row_total');
            $rowTotalIncTax = $item->getData('base_row_total_incl_tax');
            $discountAmount = $item->getData('discount_amount');
            $itemPrice = $item->getPrice();
            $itemQty = $item->getQty();
            $finalPrice = $itemPrice * $itemQty;
            // set addresses
            $quoteSplit->getBillingAddress()->setData($billingAddress);
            $quoteSplit->getShippingAddress()->setData($shippingAddress);
            $shippingAmount = $quoteSplit->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();
            // recollect totals into the quote
            foreach ($quoteSplit->getAllAddresses() as $address) {
                $address->setBaseSubtotal($finalPrice);
                $address->setSubtotal($finalPrice);
                $address->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
                $address->setTaxAmount($tax);
                $address->setBaseTaxAmount($tax);
                $address->setBaseGrandTotal($finalPrice + $shippingAmount + $tax - $discountAmount);
                $address->setGrandTotal($finalPrice + $shippingAmount + $tax - $discountAmount);
            }

            $checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quoteSplit);
            $quoteSplit->setInventoryProcessed(false);
            $quoteSplit->setCurrency($currency);
            $quoteSplit->setCheckoutMethod($checkoutMethod);
            $quoteSplit->setPaymentMethod($paymentMethod1);
            $quoteSplit->setSendCconfirmation(1);


            $quote111 = $checkoutSession->getQuote();  // or load by id
            $payment1 = $quote111->getPayment();
            $instance1 = $payment1->getMethodInstance();
            $ccNumber = $instance1->getInfoInstance()->getCcNumber();
            $ccMethod = $instance1->getInfoInstance()->getMethod();
            $ccType = $instance1->getInfoInstance()->getCcType();
            $ccExpYear = $instance1->getInfoInstance()->getCcExpYear();
            $ccExpMonth = $instance1->getInfoInstance()->getCcExpMonth();

            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test1.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info($instance1->getInfoInstance());

            return "Hello";
            $quoteSplit->getPayment()->importData(array(
                'method' => $paymentMethod1,
                'cc_type' => 'VI',
                'cc_number' => '4111111111111111',
                'cc_exp_year' => '20',
                'cc_exp_month' => '12',
                'cc_cid' => '123'
            ));        

            $quoteSplit->setIsActive(1);
```

I have tried with static value and it's working fine like below example

```
$quoteSplit->getPayment()->importData(array(
    'method' => $paymentMethod1,
    'cc_type' => 'VI',
    'cc_number' => '4111111111111111',
    'cc_exp_year' => '20',
    'cc_exp_month' => '12',
    'cc_cid' => '123'
));
```

I want to get credit card details in this file and use in creating order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by below code snap not sure that this the correct way or not.

```
$paymentDetails = $paymentCardDetails = '';
                $postData = file_get_contents("php://input");//Get all param
                $postData = (array)json_decode($postData);//Decode all json param
                foreach ($postData as $key => $value) {
                    if ($key == 'paymentMethod') { //Get paymentMethod details
                        $paymentDetails = (array)$value;
                        foreach ($paymentDetails as $key1 => $paymentValue) {
                            if ($key1 == 'additional_data') { //get  paymentMethod Details like card details
                                $paymentCardDetails = (array)$paymentValue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                $quoteSplit->getPayment()->importData(
                    array(
                        'method' => $paymentMethod1,
                        'cc_type' => $paymentCardDetails['cc_type'],
                        'cc_number' => $paymentCardDetails['cc_number'],
                        'cc_exp_year' => $paymentCardDetails['cc_exp_year'],
                        'cc_exp_month' => $paymentCardDetails['cc_exp_month'],
                        'cc_cid' => $paymentCardDetails['cc_cid']
                    )
                );
```

I tried lots but don't find any other way. Correct me if I am doing wrong.